# What encode format is Dymola using?

Tags: utf-8, modelica, dymola

I am using Modelica_DeviceDrivers Library(MDD) to send data of utf-8 format via UDP, accord to the explanation of authors of MDD, `MDD simply transfers the "const char*" byte buffer which it gets from the Modelica tool.`  But I am not sure what encoding format is Dymola using. Anyone could help me with this issue? 
Here is the question on [Github](https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/Modelica_DeviceDrivers/issues/337)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dymola 2018 FD01 and later versions encode strings in the model using UTF-8.

(However, Dymola 2016 FD01 (and some earlier versions) encoded strings with CESU-8; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8 )